# User can't access correct Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We're a very small company, for unknown reasons our internal app infrastructure (based on PaaS VMs) was set up on the Azure subscription for a "personal" Windows Live account of an internal email address, with only that one user in the AD. (We also use the "correct" Azure instance, the AD is synced from the remnant of our old on-prem infrastructure and our Office 365 is based on it.)

We're about to recruit a second developer, I want to give him some level of access to our app infrastructure but not the global admin that sharing the existing single account would provide. I've experimentally added another user to the Azure AD as a global admin (so it should have access to everything) but when I log in with that user it takes me to the portal for the default free personal Azure instance you get if there's nothing set up. If I paste in a URL for a resource in the account it's global admin for I get "You do not have access" (403). (Audit trail of the user in Azure AD shows it logged in.)

Is there an inherent restriction on this type of account (in which case I'll have to bite the bullet and migrate the infrastructure where it belongs) or should I be able to expect this user to be able to access the right portal - and if so what do I need to do to get that to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Having Global Admin role in Azure AD does not give you access to Azure resources, only to manage users etc. in Azure AD.

You need to add e.g. Owner/Contributor role on the subscription to the user through the Access Control (IAM) tab.

Comment: Thanks for that, I see what you mean now.!